# Jenkins-List SVN Folders

Tags: svn, recursion, jenkins, directory

So currently setting up Jenkins to automate our deployment process, I have almost done and was told by my boss to add another feature.

The  feature is that the developer gets to choose a branch to deploy. We currently (Next project is to change this) use SVN as our VCS.

Our SVN Structure is like this

Project1

- Project1/branches
- Project1/branches/features
- Project1/branches/features/featureA
- Project1/branches/features/featureB
- Project1/branches/testing
- Project1/branches/testing/testing1
- Project1/branches/testing/testing1
- Project1/tags/1.0
- Project1/tags/2.0
- Project1/trunk

Developers need to be able to choose from this list.

So when I used the List SVN tags (and more) I pointed it to https://svn.mycompany.com/project1 which worked fine.

and it listed only

- branch/testing
- branch/feature
- tags/1.0
- tags/2.0
- trunk

How do I recursivesly go through testing and feature to list all those specfic folders... I can't use the dynamic choice parameter

Comment: My team and I have a similar situation. Did you get to solve it?

Comment: Yeah. Well.. It was hack wasn't the greatest. I just wrote a simple python script that runs before, and checks if there are any new branches added, hten updates a properties file which jenkins grabed. I was going to work on a plugin that did it for me but it wasn't the top priority at the time.